# How much does the box weigh?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Tyrone has a box full of rocks. He doesn't have a scale to weigh it. There's a piece of paper taped to the box that looks like this:

[image: PUZZLE]

What's the weight of the box?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [image]
>  There is only one path adhering to the arrows that takes from one edge square to the other. It points the 1 to the 3.
>  The letters anagram to KILOGRAM. So perhaps the box weighs **13 kg**.